# Expo ios 15 show needs to be updated when launch enterprise signed application

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I installed an application in iOS 15 that are distributed internally and signed with enterprise distribution (no app store). However it show “My App Name” Needs to be updated. The developer of this app needs to update it to work with this version of iOS.
The app is working fine below iOS 15.

Current expo version that I'm using is sdk 36. Tried to rebuild with expo build:ios but the issue still exist. How do I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the normal build:ios command I used the new eas build command. This created an ipa which works on ios 15 by adding "image":"latest" in the eas.json file.

docs.expo.dev/build/setup

Comment: have any solution how to fix it? i could not find any solution from google

Comment: Yes I have found a solution. Instead of using the normal build:ios command I used the new eas build command. This created an ipa which works on ios 15.

https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/

Comment: the eas command work with sdk 36?

Comment: I don't think so, it says available as of 41

Comment: need to subscript in order to use EAS Build? that mean expo no longer provide free services?

Comment: @samf3u hi and thanks for posting on SO.  Please note your answer isn't an answer and will receive downvotes.  Consider adding it as a comment.  Thank you!

Comment: FYI: EAS Build has been available for free for months now. And before that it was possible to build for free locally with `eas build --local`. But as mentioned above, only for SDK 41 and up